# Add caching to __new__

Tags: python, caching, python-attrs

I have a frozen class (decorated with `attrs.frozen`). However, the program might have to create many instances of that class. Since they are immutable and I only want to read from them, I want some caching behaviors so that objects with the same data (created using the same arguments) are retrieved rather than created.

I have a working implementation but do not know if there could be any potential pitfalls.

```
from typing import ClassVar

from attrs import frozen

@frozen
class Cached:
    _cache: ClassVar[dict[str, "Cached"]] = {}

    name: str
    config: int

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwds):
        key = str(args) + str(kwds)

        if (instance:=cls._cache.get(key)) is not None:
            print("cache misses")
            return instance

        print("cache hits")
        instance = super().__new__(cls)
        instance.__init__(*args, **kwds)
        cls._cache[key] = instance
        return instance
```

Here is some results in ipython:

```
In [1]: from cached_new import Cached

In [2]: c0 = Cached("cache", 0)
cache hits

In [3]: c1 = Cached("cache", 0)
cache misses

In [4]: c0 is c1
Out[4]: True

In [5]: c2 = Cached("", 1)
cache hits

In [6]: c3 = Cached("", 1)
cache misses

In [7]: c2 is c3
Out[7]: True
```

Comment: Are you sure the best way here is such kind of meta programming and not rather put the caching at the place of instantiation? If you have control over that it's almost always better to use a function for it instead.

Comment: I used `__new__`  to leverage the `__init__` function that `@frozen` decorator provides, but you are right. It's simpler to have a factory function (probably decorated with `functools.cache`), so I don't have to write the caching logic myself. Thank you for the suggestion.